# How to sum columns and then sort them in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

**Below is a sample DataFrame, The data is in .csv file.**

```
  EPISODE_Number EPISODE_TITLE  object1  object2  object3  object4  object5
0         S01E01             A        1        1        0        0        0
1         S01E02             B        0        0        0        1        0
2         S01E03             C        1        1        0        0        1
3         S01E04             D        0        1        1        1        0
4         S01E05             E        1        0        0        1        0
5         S01E06             F        1        1        0        1        1
6         S01E07             G        0        0        0        1        1
7         S01E08             H        0        1        0        0        0
8         S01E09             I        1        1        0        1        1
9         S01E10             J        0        1        1        0        0
```

I would like to have the sum of each object and then sort the objects from bigger to smaller (top 10 only)

**Below is my code so far:**

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("TV_show.csv")
sume_s =  data[data.sum(0).sort_values(ascending=False)[2:6].index]
```

**output should be like below:**

```
object2: 7
object4: 6
object1: 5
object5: 4
object3: 2
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
    indexer = non_nan_idx[non_nans.argsort(kind=kind)]
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

Comment: The goal is to sort based on the sum of object1 - object5?

Comment: Presumably the goal of your slice is to apply these operations only to the `object` columns, which are numeric. For that to work, the slice has to happen *before* the summing and sorting steps.

Comment: Wait. Are we sorting rows or columns?

Comment: Yes, but first I need to have the sum of each object and then sort the objects from bigger to smaller.

Comment: Always provide a [mre] with current output and **expected result**. Given the columns, it's not clear what the desired final result should be. Once that is provided, I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I added the expected output.

Comment: So just `data.iloc[:, 2:7].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)`? you're not trying to reorder columns or rows?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct code but I want the top 10 only.

Comment: Top 10 values _after_ sorting (`data.iloc[:, 2:7].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)`) or you only want to consider the first 10 rows (`data.iloc[:10, 2:7].sum().sort_values(ascending=False)`)?

Comment: sume_a = (data.iloc[:, 2:7].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10))
print(sume_a)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with sum and for top 10 add [`Series.nlargest`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html):

```
sume_a = data.iloc[:, 2:7].sum().nlargest(10)
print (sume_a)
object2    7
object4    6
object1    5
object5    4
object3    2
dtype: int64
```

Working like comment solution:

```
sume_a = data.iloc[:, 2:7].sum().sort_values(ascending=False).head(10)
```